# Filtering a collection inside a collection MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have a list of project dtos that contain a collection of tasks.  On my ViewModel I have an ICollectionView for the projects so I can filter projects that are marked as done see below filter code.

```
    public void FilterDoneItems()
    {
        if (this.MarkDone)
        {
            ProjectsViewSource.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterDone);
        }
        else
        {
            ProjectsViewSource.Filter = null;
        }
    }
```

This works fine for projects but I also want to filter out the done tasks.  As the ProjectDTO encompases the Tasks (List) I can't wrap the tasks in an ICollectionView to filter them in the ViewModel.

I am unsure how best to go about filtering on the tasks as well can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Every collection has a default CollectionView maintained by WPF, and when you bind to the collection WPF will actually bind to that view.  You can get a reference to that view by calling [CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx) and set the filter on that:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(someList).Filter = somePredicate;
```

Comment: Would I have to bind to the CollectionViewSource or could I still bind to the actual collection and have the filtering work?

Comment: @Burt: You still bind to the actual collection.  From the CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView doc: "If you bind directly to a collection, WPF actually binds to the default view for that collection."